# Puzzling behavior of QGraphicsView.fitInView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I am trying to make a widget with two QGraphicsViews to compare two images side-by-side. When the user zooms in in one of the views, the other should zoom into the same region. My zoomIn function sends a signal with the visible scene rectangle and a slot in the other view captures this signal and calls `QGraphicsView.fitInView(rectangle)` to make the same image region visible.
To my surprise, `fitInView` seems to treat the rectangle (x, y, width, height) as (x, y, x + width, y + height).
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Here is my code sample:

The `QGraphicsView` subclass

```
import logging
from PyQt5 import (
    QtWidgets as qw,
    QtCore as qc,
    QtGui as qg
)

class Display(qw.QGraphicsView):
    sigViewportAreaChanged = qc.pyqtSignal(qc.QRectF)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Display, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
        self.zoomInAction = qw.QAction('Zoom in')
        self.zoomInAction.triggered.connect(self.zoomIn)

    @qc.pyqtSlot()
    def zoomIn(self):
        self.scale(1.2, 1.2)
        pos = self.viewport().pos()
        size = self.viewport().size()
        logging.debug(f'{self.objectName()}: viewport:: pos: {pos}, size: {size}')
        pos = self.mapToScene(pos)
        size = self.mapToScene(size.width(), size.height())
        logging.debug(f'{self.objectName()}: scene:: pos: {pos}, size: {size}')
        view_area = qc.QRectF(pos.x(), pos.y(), size.x(), size.y())
        logging.debug(
            f'Emitting changed viewport area, {view_area},\n{mat}')
        self.sigViewportAreaChanged.emit(view_area)

    def setViewportRect(self, rect: qc.QRectF) -> None:
        logging.debug(f'{self.objectName()} <- {self.sender().objectName()}\nFit view to {rect}')
        pos = self.viewport().pos()
        size = self.viewport().size()
        logging.debug(f'{self.objectName()}: before fitting area: viewport:: pos: {pos}, size: {size}')
        pos = self.mapToScene(pos)
        size = self.mapToScene(size.width(), size.height())
        logging.debug(f'{self.objectName()}: before fitting area: scene:: pos: {pos}, size: {size}')
        # self.fitInView(rect)  # Incorrectly sets the visible area
        self.fitInView(rect.x(), rect.y(), rect.width() - rect.x(), rect.height() - rect.y())  # this works
        pos = self.viewport().pos()
        size = self.viewport().size()
        logging.debug(f'{self.objectName()}: after fitting area: viewport:: pos: {pos}, size: {size}')
        pos = self.mapToScene(pos)
        size = self.mapToScene(size.width(), size.height())
        logging.debug(f'{self.objectName()}: after fitting area: scene:: pos: {pos}, size: {size}')  # this suggests that the new viewport is (x, y, x+width, y+height) instead of (x, y, width, height)
```

The container widget:

```
class ReviewWidget(qw.QWidget):
    """A widget with two panes for comparing images"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReviewWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = qw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.before = Display()
        self.before.setObjectName('Left')
        self.after = Display()
        self.after.setObjectName('Right')
        self.before.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(qc.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.before.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(qc.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.after.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(qc.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.after.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(qc.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        panes_layout = qw.QHBoxLayout()
        panes_layout.addWidget(self.before)
        panes_layout.addWidget(self.after)
        layout.addLayout(panes_layout)
        self.setLayout(panes_layout)
        self.make_actions()

    def tieViews(self, tie):
        if tie:
            self.before.sigViewportAreaChanged.connect(self.after.setViewportRect)
            self.after.sigViewportAreaChanged.connect(self.before.setViewportRect)
       else:
            self.before.disconnect(self.before.sigViewportAreaChanged)
            self.after.disconnect(self.after.sigViewportAreaChanged)

    def make_actions(self):
        self.tieViewsAction = qw.QAction('Zoom views together')
        self.tieViewsAction.setCheckable(True)
        self.tieViewsAction.triggered.connect(self.tieViews)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the way you're calculating `size` is wrong. You should calculate it relative to the translated value of `pos`. Since you know the values for width and height, you can calculate `view_area`'s  lower right corner based on the scene value of `pos`.

```py
viewport_pos = self.viewport().pos()
scene_pos = self.mapToScene(viewport_pos)

width = self.viewport().size().width()
height = self.viewport().size().height()

lower_right_corner = QPointF(width - scene_pos.x(), height() - scene_pos.y())
```

Without the subtraction you're assuming that the origin of `view_area` is at `(0, 0)` when in fact it is `pos`.

Comment: I thought width and height should be independent of the origin, as they measure an interval in space (i.e., the length of a line should not change depending the origin of the coordinate system is). Now I understand that the `mapToScene` on the size treated it as a point and translated it for change of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured my mistake after reading answer by @Roney Gomes.

In order to scale the size to scene coordinate system I was passing the size as a point to `mapToScene`.

But point and size are conceptually different, while size does not depend on the origin of the coordinate system, point does.
`mapToScene`, treating its argument as a point, was translating it to reflect the new coordinate system.

Hence I need to subtract the origin of the new coordinate system, which is practically the top left corner of the viewport, to get back the size.

A simpler solution is to directly map the viewport rectangle:

```
rect = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().rect())  
rect = rect.boundingRect() # mapToScene(rect) returns QPolygonF
self.sigViewportAreaChanged.emit(rect)
```